# Return Collatz Conjecture for matrix with n<-1:30 with R loop

Tags: r, collatz

I am new to R.  There is plenty on here and the rest of the web around writing functions to return the Collatz conjecture for a given integer.

As such, i have managed to create a function that will:

```
numseq <- function(num)
{
  if(num == 1)
    return(NULL)

  if(num %% 2 == 0)
    return(num / 2)

  return(3 * num + 1)
}

seqfetch <- function(input)
{
  result <- input
  while(input != 1)
  {
    input <- numseq(input)
    result <- c(result, input)
  }
  return(result)
}

seqfetch(15)
```

However i have a vector `nums<-1:30` and am trying to loop through each element of it and run the function against it, outputting the values for each iteration and each value of n.

I am aiming for:

n = 2: `[1] 2 1`

n = 3: `[1]  3 10  5 16  8  4  2  1`

...

...

...

n = 30: `[1]  30  15  46  23  70  35 106  53 160  80  40  20  10   5  16   8   4   2   1`

And so on...

I dont know a lot about R and have tried wrapping the whole thing in a loop.  I have also tried the same thing with a matrix of one column.  I get an error saying that only the first element will be used.

Can anyone help with the loop please?  Or am i going about it the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: `lapply(1:30, seqfetch)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, rewriting `numseq` as a recursive function.

```
numseq <- function(num) {
  if(num == 1)
    num
  else if(num %% 2 == 0)
    c(num, numseq(num / 2))
  else
    c(num, numseq(3 * num + 1))
}
```

Now all you have to do is

```
lapply(1:30, numseq)
```

Or, in the form of a function,

```
seqfetch2 <- function(input){
  lapply(input, numseq)
}

seqfetch2(1:30)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Seems a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to acheive the desired output using sapply().
By wrapping function 2 in sapply() as below:

```
sapply(1:30, function(input)
{
  result <- input
  while(input != 1)
  {
    input <- numseq(input)
    result <- c(result, input)   
  }
  return(result)
}
)
```

I acheived the desired output of:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 1

[[3]]
[1]  3 10  5 16  8  4  2  1

[[4]]
[1] 4 2 1

[[5]]
[1]  5 16  8  4  2  1

[[6]]
[1]  6  3 10  5 16  8  4  2  1

[[7]]
 [1]  7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10  5 16  8  4  2  1

[[8]]
[1] 8 4 2 1

[[9]]
 [1]  9 28 14  7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10  5 16  8  4  2  1
```

And so on through to 30.